# Javascript - Roll20 API Script

Tags: javascript

I play a game on roll20 and I am writing a script to add macros to a "Character", I have made a script which will add all of the skills, but I dont know how to write logic to have it check if the attribute exists on the character sheet then write the macro.

So here is my code, and some suggestions would be great! I am a noob to all of this and I am working on learning the language, but I could use an example to work with!

```
        var bigmike = bigmike || {};

        bigmike.dicetype = "1d20";

        bigmike.charClasses = [
                'Monster'
        ];

        bigmike.attribute = [];
            bigmike.attribute["AC"] = { name: "AC", current: "", max:"" };
            bigmike.attribute["Init"] = { name: "Init", current: "", max:"" };
            bigmike.attribute["fort"] = { name: "Fort", current: "", max:"" };
            bigmike.attribute["ref"] = { name: "Ref", current: "", max:"" };
            bigmike.attribute["will"] = { name: "Will", current: "", max:"" };
            bigmike.attribute["str"] = { name: "Str", current: "", max:"" };      
            bigmike.attribute["dex"] = { name: "Dex", current: "", max:"" };
            bigmike.attribute["con"] = { name: "Con", current: "", max:"" };
            bigmike.attribute["int"] = { name: "Int", current: "", max:"" };
            bigmike.attribute["wis"] = { name: "Wis", current: "", max:"" };
            bigmike.attribute["cha"] = { name: "Cha", current: "", max:"" };
            bigmike.attribute["Size"] = { name: "Size", current: "", max:"" };
            bigmike.attribute["CR"] = { name: "CR", current: "", max:"" };
            bigmike.attribute["HP"] = { name: "HP", current: "", max:"" };
            bigmike.attribute["BaseAtk"] = { name: "BaseAtk", current: "", max:"" };
            bigmike.attribute["CMB"] = { name: "CMB", current: "", max:"" };
            bigmike.attribute["CMD"] = { name: "CMD", current: "", max:"" };


        bigmike.stats = [
            { name: bigmike.attribute["str"].name },
            { name: bigmike.attribute["dex"].name },
            { name: bigmike.attribute["con"].name },
            { name: bigmike.attribute["int"].name },
            { name: bigmike.attribute["wis"].name },
            { name: bigmike.attribute["cha"].name }
        ]; 

        bigmike.saves = [
            { name: bigmike.attribute["fort"].name },
            { name: bigmike.attribute["ref"].name },
            { name: bigmike.attribute["will"].name }
        ];

        /** Skills
        Skills are represented as an object, which consists of one value, since Monsters have static skill settings.
         */
        bigmike.skill = [
            { name: "Acrobatics", start: 0 },
            { name: "Appraise", start: 0 },
            { name: "Bluff", start: 0 },
            { name: "Climb", start: 0 },
            { name: "Diplomacy", start: 0 },
            { name: "Disable-Device", start: 0 },
            { name: "Disguise", start: 0 },
            { name: "Escape-Artist", start: 0 },
            { name: "Fly", start: 0 },
            { name: "Handle-Animal", start: 0 },
            { name: "Heal", start: 0 },
            { name: "Intimidate", start: 0 },
            { name: "Linguistics", start: 0 },
            { name: "Perception", start: 0 },
            { name: "Perform", start: 0 },
            { name: "Ride", start: 0 },
            { name: "Sense-Motive", start: 0 },
            { name: "Sleight-of-Hand", start: 0 },
            { name: "Spellcraft", start: 0 },
            { name: "Stealth", start: 0 },
            { name: "Survival", start: 0 },
            { name: "Swim", start: 0 },
            { name: "Use-Magic-Device", start: 0 }
        ];

        bigmike.knowledge = [
            { name: "Knowledge-Arcana", start: 0 },
            { name: "Knowledge-Dungeoneering", start: 0 },
            { name: "Knowledge-Engineering", start: 0 },
            { name: "Knowledge-Geography", start: 0 },
            { name: "Knowledge-History", start: 0 },
            { name: "Knowledge-Local", start: 0 },
            { name: "Knowledge-Nature", start: 0 },
            { name: "Knowledge-Nobility", start: 0 },
            { name: "Knowledge-Planes", start: 0 },
            { name: "Knowledge-Religion", start: 0 }
        ];

        bigmike.craft = [
            { name: "Craft-Any", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Alchemy", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Armorer", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Basketweaving", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Bookbinding", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Bowyer", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Blacksmith", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Brewing", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Calligraphy", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Carpentry", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Cobbling", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Cooking", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Crystal-Carving", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Gemcutting", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Glassblowing", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Goldsmith", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Leatherworking", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Locksmithing", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Jewelry", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Painting", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Pottery", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Sculpting", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Stonemasonry", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Tailoring", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Traps", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Weaponsmith", start: 0 },
            { name: "Craft-Weaving", start: 0 }
        ];

        bigmike.parseCommand = function parseCommand(msg) {
            if (msg.type == "api" && msg.who.indexOf("(GM)") == -1) {
                sendChat("System", "Only the GM is allowed to switch classes.");
                return;
            }
            if(msg.type == "api" && msg.content.indexOf("!skill ") !== -1) {
                var cmdParts = msg.content.replace("!skill ", "").split(" ");
                var charClass;

                _.each(cmdParts, function(part) {
                    var indexOfClass = _.indexOf(bigmike.charClasses, part);
                    if (indexOfClass > -1) {
                        charClass = bigmike.charClasses[indexOfClass];
                        cmdParts = _.without(cmdParts, part);
                    }
                });

                if (typeof charClass === undefined) {
                    sendChat('System', 'Usage: !skill charName charClass');
                    sendChat('System', 'Value for charClass: ' + bigmike.charClasses);
                    return;
                }

                var result = {};
                result.charName = cmdParts.join(" ");
                log("Charname: " + result.charName);
                result.charType = charClass;
                log("CharType: " + result.charType);
                return result;
            }
        }

        on("ready", function() {
            sendChat("system", "/w GM API is ready and running");
            on("add:character", function(character) {
        //        insertAttributes(character);
        //        insertStatRolls(character);
                insertSaves(character);
        //        insertAttacks(character);
                insertSkills(character);
                insertKnowledges(character);
                insertCrafts(character);
            });
        });

        on("chat:message", function(msg) {
                var chatCmd = bigmike.parseCommand(msg);
                if (typeof chatCmd === 'undefined') {
                    return;
                }

                sendChat('System', 'Setting class ' + chatCmd.charType + ' for ' + chatCmd.charName);

                var characters = findObjs({
                    _type: "character",
                    archived: false,
                    name: chatCmd.charName
                }, {caseInsensitive: true});
                _.each(characters, function(character) {
                    log("Name: " + character.get("name"));
                    log("Bio: " + character.get("bio"));
                    log("GM-Notes: " + character.get("gmnotes"));
                    log("Archived: " + character.get("archived"));
                    log("In player journals: " + character.get("inplayerjournals"));
                    log("Controlled By: " + character.get("controlledby"));
                    insertSaves(character, chatCmd.charType);
                    insertSkills(character, chatCmd.charType);
                    insertKnowledges(character, chatCmd.charType);
                    insertCrafts(character, chatCmd.charType);
                });
            });

        /** Functions
            list of functions: (planned or in place) 
                insertAttribute
                insertAbilities
                insertSkills
                rollStats
        */

        function insertAttributes(character) {
            for (var index in bigmike.attribute) {
                createObj("attribute", {
                    name: bigmike.attribute[index].name,
                    current: bigmike.attribute[index].start,
                    max: bigmike.attribute[index].max,
                    characterid: character.id
                });
            };
            for(var index in bigmike.skill) {
                createObj("attribute", {
                    name: bigmike.skill[index].name,
                    current: bigmike.skill[index].start,
                    max: "",
                    characterid: character.id,
                });
            };
            for(var index = 0; index < bigmike.knowledge.length; index++) {
                createObj(".attribute", {
                    name: bigmike.knowledge[index].name,
                    current: bigmike.knowledge[index].start,
                    max: "",
                    characterid: character.id,
                });
            };
        };

        function insertAttacks(character) {
            for (var index = 0; index < bigmike.attack.length; index++) {
                createObj("ability", {
                    name: bigmike.attack[index].name,
                    description: "",   
                    action: bigmike.attack[index].macro,   
                    characterid: character.id,
                });
            };
        }

        function insertSkills(character) {
            for (var index = 0; index < bigmike.skill.length; index++) {
                var macro =  "/emas @{selected|token_name} makes a check vs " + bigmike.skill[index].name + " ( [[" + bigmike.dicetype + " + @{" + bigmike.skill[index].name + "} ]] )";
                createObj("ability", {
                    name: bigmike.skill[index].name,
                    description: "",   
                    action: macro,   
                    characterid: character.id
                });
            };
        }

        function insertKnowledges(character) {
            for (var index = 0; index < bigmike.knowledge.length; index++) {
                var macro =  "/emas @{selected|token_name} makes a check vs " + bigmike.knowledge[index].name + ": ( [[" + bigmike.dicetype + "+@{" + bigmike.knowledge[index].name + "} ]] )";
                createObj("ability", {
                    name: bigmike.knowledge[index].name,
                    description: "",   
                    action: macro,   
                    characterid: character.id
                });
            };
        }

        function insertCrafts(character) {
            for (var index = 0; index < bigmike.craft.length; index++) {
                var macro =  "/emas @{selected|token_name} makes a check vs " + bigmike.craft[index].name + ": ( [[" + bigmike.dicetype + "+@{" + bigmike.craft[index].name + "} ]] )";
                createObj("ability", {
                    name: bigmike.craft[index].name,
                    description: "",   
                    action: macro,   
                    characterid: character.id
                });
            };
        }

        function insertStatRolls(character) {
            for (var index = 0; index < bigmike.stats.length; index++) {
                var macro =  "/emas @{selected|token_name} rolls a [[" + bigmike.dicetype + "+@{" + bigmike.stats[index].name + "} ]] for his " + bigmike.stats[index].name + " check.";
                createObj("ability", {
                    name: bigmike.stats[index].name,
                    description: "",   
                    action: macro,   
                    characterid: character.id
                });
            };
        }

        function insertSaves(character) {
            for (var index = 0; index < bigmike.saves.length; index++) {
                var macro =  "/emas @{selected|token_name} rolls a [[" + bigmike.dicetype + "+@{" + bigmike.saves[index].name + "} ]] save VS " + bigmike.saves[index].name + ".";
                createObj("ability", {
                    name: bigmike.saves[index].name,
                    description: "",   
                    action: macro,   
                    characterid: character.id
                });
            };
        }
```

Comment: This script provides two functions, the first is to create all of the attributes and macros on a new character, the second function is through the  chat system by invoking it and will modify a existing object. https://wiki.roll20.net/API:Introduction

Comment: Come on guys, this is childs play for you!

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with Roll20's API just yet, but can't you just check to see if it's empty?

`bigmike.attribute['AC'] !== undefined;`

Answer (score 1):

To search for existing attribute(s) you don't know the _id of, use `findObjs`:

```
function insertAttributes(character) {
    var characterAttrs = findObjs({
        _type: 'attribute',
        //name: 'MyAttrName',
        _characterid: character.id
    });
    // `characterAttrs` is now an array of all attributes owned by `character`
    // If you uncomment the name line and `character` has one or more attributes
    // named "MyAttrName", `characterAttrs` will be an array of all of the
    // attributes named "MyAttrName" owned by `character`

    ...
}
```

More information can be found on the [Roll20 Wiki](https://wiki.roll20.net/API%3aIntroduction).

FWIW, you also have a lot of extraneous semicolons in your code (such as at the end of a `for` loop block). In your knowledge attribute loop, you're also trying to create an object of type `.attribute`, not `attribute`. You also have access to [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) when writing Roll20 scripts, which  can be exceptionally useful.

For future reference, the Roll20.net message board has a forum *specifically* for asking for help with Roll20 API scripts (and showing off completed scripts). The users there will be able to help you much more quickly than here on SO. While SO is usually very fast, the Roll20 API is used only on Roll20, so it's a very localized question.